# Extracting data from XML into a csv file using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

My objective is to get all  data from an XML file. So I tried to parse the XML using beautifulSoup and tried to extract it all in a single .csv file.

My XML look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<jobs>
    <job>
        <title>
            <![CDATA[Personal Shopper]]>
        </title>
        <date>
            <![CDATA[Sat, 05 Dec 2020 12:25:52 UTC]]>
        </date>
        <referencenumber>
            <![CDATA[12312414141]]>
        </referencenumber>
        <city>
            <![CDATA[Powell]]>
        </city>
        <state>
            <![CDATA[Washington]]>
        </state>
        <country>
            <![CDATA[US]]>
        </country>
        <postalcode>
            <![CDATA[98388]]>
        </postalcode>
        <salary>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </salary>
        <description>
            <![CDATA[Sample of description]]>
        </description>
    </job>
    <job>
        <title>
            <![CDATA[CEO]]>
        </title>
        <date>
            <![CDATA[Sat, 28 Nov 2020 00:54:32 UTC]]>
        </date>
        <referencenumber>
            <![CDATA[1231314211241412]]>
        </referencenumber>
        <city>
            <![CDATA[peanut]]>
        </city>            <country>
            <![CDATA[US]]>
        </country>
        <postalcode>
            <![CDATA[01961]]>
        </postalcode>
        <description>
            <![CDATA[sample of description]]>
        </description>
        <source>
        <![CDATA[Get me a job]]>
        </source>
        <cpc>0.36</cpc>
    </job>
```

I used this .py codes below which supposed to print out all reference number from the XML into a csv file, however it only extracted out 1 reference_number from my xml file? Can someone point out which part I did wrong?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
fd = open('/users/minion/downloads/goodnight.xml')
xml_file = fd.read()
output_csv = "output.csv"

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_file,'html.parser')

with open(output_csv, 'w') as fout:
    #print header
    header="idx,reference_number"
    fout.write("{}\n".format(header))

    for idx,tag in enumerate(soup.findAll("referencenumber")):
        data_row="{},{}".format(idx,tag)

    fout.write("{}\n".format(data_row))


fd.close()
```

Comment: have you looked into `xmlns` library?

Comment: First, to parse xml files, you are probably better off using lxml, which supports xpath 1.0. Second, what do you expect the values of `data_row` to be?

Comment: Thanks guys, edited the below part and it worked like a charm!!

for idx,tag in enumerate(soup.findAll("referencenumber")):
data_row="{},{}".format(idx,tag)